# Add Multiple Annotations/Labels to CandlestickPlot in CorePlot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I am using Coreplot library to show a `CandlestickPlot`. The default implementation only has a single `CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation` attached to each plot in the graph(Highest value in OHLC/CandleStickPlot). I want to show two values for High as well as Low. 
I tried adding below code but no luck.

```
CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *labelAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:self.plotSpace anchorPlotPoint:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:newX, newY, nil]];
labelAnnotation.annotationHostLayer = label.annotationHostLayer;
labelAnnotation.contentLayer = label.contentLayer;
[self addAnnotation:labelAnnotation];
```

[`label` is the default annotation displayed]

Answer (score 0):

1. An annotation cannot share a content layer with another annotation. You'll need to create a new layer for the annotation content. `CPTTextLayer` is a common choice, but it can be any `CPTLayer`.
2. What is `self` in this context? The default plot data label annotations are added to the plot; you should add your secondary plot labels to the plot, too.